# Windows Server 2008 Files Not Appearing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been tasked with solving an issue in which all of the files on a network drive are no longer appearing. From what I've been told, everything was working properly, and then one user upgraded their PC to Windows 10. After the update, all of the files on the network drive no longer appear. However, they still appeared when the drive was accessed from another PC running Windows 7.

I accessed the server remotely to assess the issue, and found that the files weren't showing up in the file explorer. I tried changing permissions for the user accounts on the drive and now the files won't appear on the Windows 7 PC either (even after reverting the permissions). The disk properties still show a bunch of space being taken up by the files. I tried creating a new directory on the drive and this worked, but it's the only directory that will appear.

I've tried running chkdsk and sfc /scannow, and neither of these showed any issues.

I've researched this issue for a few hours and I haven't been able to find anything to point me in the right direction. I'm guessing there's probably some obvious stuff that I haven't tried yet (I'm a web developer so this is pretty outside of my skill set), so I'd be grateful if somebody with more experience with issues like this could help me out.

At the time of writing I'm realizing I didn't screenshot the "empty" directory. However, at the top of the chkdsk screenshot is the output from the "tree" command, which shows only the test directory that I created.

Disk properties

[image: Disk properties]

System info

[image: Server info]

Chkdsk results

[image: chkdsk]

Sfc /scannow results

[image: sfc scannow]

Answer (score 1):

Server 2008 likely has SMBv1 enabled. It is an old OS. Windows 10 is SMBv2 and no longer navigates SMBv1.

Use the article below to enable SMBv2 on Server 2008. Restart the server after making the changes and then test your Windows 10 machine.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

When testing, open a Command Prompt on the Windows 10 machine and type:

NET USE  Z: \servername\folder.  Post any numerical error you get back here.

On the Windows 10 machine, make sure both Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both enabled and Networking is Private, not Public.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I enabled SMBv2, and when using the NET USE command here's the error it gave: "System error 55: The specified network resource or device is no longer available". First I got a "System error 85: The local device name is already in use" but I think that's because I was used the letter Z which was already in use for another drive. I also saw a "System error 67: Network name can't be found", I think I just had a typo in the servername that time.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So can you now see the files?  Seems like it.

Comment: Ha, I can't believe I didn't specify that in my comment. I still can't see them from the server or the Windows 10 machine ): Should I disable SMBv1 after enabling SMBv2?

Comment: Once SMBv2 is enabled, yes, disable SMBv1 so systems do not get confused. Restart the Server after changing this.

Comment: Also and separately from the above, make sure on the Windows 10 machine that Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both enabled and that networking is Private, not Public.

Comment: I just tried again after ensuring that SMBv1 is disabled, SMBv2 is enabled, and Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both enabled, and the files still aren't appearing on the server. On the Windows 10 machine, I'm still getting "System error 55: The specified network resource or device is no longer available"

Comment: System Error 55 can have to do with script errors. Make sure you disconnect all drives on every log off / shut down. Do a NET USE T: /Delete for all drives T, restart and log  on a drive or two and test.